# PostGIS Multipolygon - holes

Tags: postgis, polygon

I have `MULTIPOLYGON` in my PostGIS database to store countries (with islands etc.). But I need to add holes to my borders for lakes. How can I store multipolygon with holes?

I am using `ST_SetSRID(ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(...)')), 4326)` to create multipolygon

Answer (score 5):

You can use ST_Difference to create the holes.  It will subtract the lakes from your countries.

Let's say your lakes are in another table called lakes and you've already stored your countries.  You would do something like

```
UPDATE countries SET geom = ST_Difference(geom, 
       (SELECT ST_Union(l.geom) FROM lakes As l 
         WHERE ST_Intersects(l.geom, countries.geom) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from LR1234567 works OK, but I didnt want to create second table. At the end, I have create multipolygon with holes directly during geometry construction, using WKT.

```
MULTIPOLYGON (
(
   (40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)
),
(
   (20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35),(30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20) 
)
)
```

See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

Comment: if you insist on creating your polygons using WKT how else could you do this?